# (eog:4461): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display when trying to use eog to open images on Windows via SSH

Tags: 16.04, remote, mir, eog

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 And when I try to use eog to open images on windows 10 While using SSH it says:

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: no such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(eog:4461): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :1
```

Any Help?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu Desktop? Are you using the local desktop (the graphical desktop) or are you connecting remotely?

Comment: i use a console to connect

Comment: i use Terminal!

Comment: Are you connecting from another computer or are you using a terminal emulator (for example `gnome-terminal`) in the graphical desktop environment of the computer itself?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: If we get no more details, we assume, that you connect remotely. And then we think that your question is a duplicate.

Comment: i wish it was an duplicate ... I WANT THE FREAKING ANSWER TO THIS BUG

Comment: What bug? If you're trying to open a window via SSH on Windows, you need X installed and X Forwarding enabled.